# If any row has value for Cluster column, set it as Cluster of other rows as well

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have `table 1` in my database which has 2 columns: `id` and `cluster`. what I want to do:

1. set the cluster column value of the rows which have the id of 10 or 20 or 30 to A
2. if any of these 3 rows have currently a cluster value set, then take that value and set as the cluster value of all these 3 rows.

How to do it with MySQL query? For example:

**case 1**

```
id     cluster
--------------
10     NULL
20     NULL
30     NULL
```

The expected result:

```
id     cluster
--------------
10     A
20     A
30     A
```

**case 2:**

```
id     cluster
--------------
10     NULL
20     Z
30     NULL
```

The expected result:

```
id     cluster
--------------
10     Z
20     Z
30     Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a query, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(max(cluster) over (), 'A') as imputed_cluster
from t
where id in (10, 20, 30);
```

If you want an update:

```
update t join
       (select max(cluster) as cluster
        from t
        where id in (10, 20, 30)
       ) tt
    set cluster = coalesce(tt.cluster, 'A')
    where t.id in (10, 20, 30)
```

Comment: many thanks. but why have you used `max()`?

Comment: @Soheil . . . This is using a window function.  `MAX()` is appropriate because it returns one value and ignores `NULL` values.